# Entity Framework core can't truncate DateTime using MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm using the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL provider.
When I try to execute this Linq query:

```cs
MeetingUsers.Where(m => m.Meeting.FromDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) && m.Meeting.FromDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(2)).Include(m => m.Meeting)
    .GroupBy(m => m.Meeting.FromDate.Date)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
        Count = g.Count(),
        Responses = g.GroupBy(x => x.Response).Select(x => new { Response = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList()
    });
```

I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side. This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain simple property access expressions.

I want to group the result by date only not by DateTime.

When I tried to remove the Date from the group by It works perfectly as following:

```
MeetingUsers.Where(m => m.Meeting.FromDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) && m.Meeting.FromDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(2)).Include(m => m.Meeting)
    .GroupBy(m => m.Meeting.FromDate)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
        Count = g.Count(),
        Responses = g.GroupBy(x => x.Response).Select(x => new { Response = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList()
    });
```

But now It Groupby date and time. So how I can group by date only using EF Core with MySql?

Comment: Why are you using `Responses = g.GroupBy(x => x.Response).Select(x => new { Response = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList()    });`? What are you trying to generate? The error complains about the entire query and tells you it can't be translated to SQL. What SQL query are you trying to emulate?

Comment: `how I can group by date only using EF Core with MySql` which MySQL provider are you using? Oracle's provider has so many bugs most people have moved to the truly open source [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) provider. Pomelo has almost *twice* the downloads of Oracle's provider and fixes many of the bugs Oracle refuses to fix

Comment: The query still needs fixing though. This looks like an attempt to add a `GROUP BY` subquery in the `SELECT` clause, which will either fail or return unexpected results. There can't be multiple results in a SELECT field. If you want to group *responses* by meeting and date, you need to start from `Responses`, not `MeetingUsers`.

Comment: But the query works and return the desired result if I removed the date casting as I mentioned. Then Why it fails when I add it. and how I can group by Date only if the filed contains DateTime.

Comment: What I want to achieve is for every day I want the number of meeting attendees grouped by their response to attend the meeting.

Comment: Which provider did you use? Oracle's may not translate `.Date` at all. Have you tried using Pomelo?

Comment: It is failed because EF Core's Eager Loading algorithm failed to generate query. Your query is not directly translatable to the SQL and EF Core translator trying to solve this puzzle. My answer will produce desired result and query will be much more faster.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv if the problem is `.Date`, it may be that the Oracle driver doesn't translate `FromDate.Date` to `Date(FromDate)`. The query definitely needs cleaning up though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, nope `Unable to translate a collection subquery...` it is original error message. I see in this query Eager Loading which failed to translate.

Comment: Pomelo *does* convert `.Date`. There was as even a similar question in [the EF Core Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27448) and guess what - the answer was to use Pomelo

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the OP also says that `removing the cast works`. The provider emits this error which means it could be *another* bug in Oracle's provider. There's no point trying to troubleshot Connector/.NET.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it is because without `cast`, Eager Loading algorithm can trace back required properties for client side post processing. I'm just looking from LINQ Translator perspective.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv with Pomelo or Oracle? The cast works in Pomelo, doesn't work in Oracle's driver [and here's the GH issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27448)

Comment: I am already using Pomelo not Oracle provider.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed, just remove `Responses = g.GroupBy(x => x.Response)..,` part to clarify that this is Eager Loading issue, not just `cast`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's not `cast`, the OP said they use Pomelo. That's not eager loading though. That expression *isn't* a GROUP BY, it returns the data in a hierarchical shape (parent/children). This works in *some* providers because they return the flat data *then* reshape it. Or they may need to use split queries

Comment: Or rather, it's not the cast alone, but the fact it's inside `GroupBy()`, that causes the flat-then-rehydrate operation to fail. This could be solved by casting *before* grouping

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv When I remove ther `Response = g.GroupBy(x => ......` line, the query works fine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I know what I mean. I have developed Eager Loading for `linq2db`, such nuances are clear after that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest in this case, do grouping on the client side.

```cs
var minimal = await MeetingUsers
    .Where(m => m.Meeting.FromDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) && m.Meeting.FromDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(2))
    .Select(m => new { m.Meeting.FromDate, m.Response })
    .ToListAsync();

var result = minimal
    .GroupBy(m => m.FromDate.Date)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
        Count = g.Count(),
        Responses = g.GroupBy(x => x.Response).Select(x => new { Response = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList()
    });
```